# How to insert labels in the corner of each table element

Tags: tables, formatting

How could I insert some references in the corner of each table element so I could reference the text from them?
This is the current product:

```
\newcommand{\RowSize}{3cm}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{\RowSize}|p{\RowSize}|p{\RowSize}|}

\hline
One & Two & Three \\
\hline
Four & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\
\hline
Seven & Eight & Nine \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

---

This is where I wish to go

*Note:* Take in mind the text is not restricted to be small as in the ilustration
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps do something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \AtBeginEnvironment
\usepackage{alphalph} % should you need more than 26 labels in a table

\newcounter{CL} % make a new counter for cell labels
\newcommand\CL{\refstepcounter{CL}\hfill\AlphAlph{\value{CL}}} % \CL will increase the counter and print its value as a capital letter
\newcommand{\RowSize}{3cm}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{CL}{0}} % reset counter at every tabular
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{\RowSize}|p{\RowSize}|p{\RowSize}|}
\hline
One \CL & Two \CL & Three \CL \\
\hline
Four \CL & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\
\hline
Seven  \CL& Eight \CL & Nine \CL \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following might be useful. The placement of the label is always at the top right corner of the cell. If you use `\labelcell` prior to any content the content is shifted downwards for one row. If you use it after the content, the content will not be moved. This is a funny side effect of the `\label` macro which I think is very useful in this context for cells with much content. The vertical offset of the content appears only in `p`-type columns, though.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcounter{labelcellcount}[table]
%% appearance how it is put at the end of the cell
\newcommand\incelllabelcellcount
  {%
    \llap{\textcolor{gray}{\thelabelcellcount}}%
  }
%% overall appearance of the counter
\renewcommand\thelabelcellcount
  {%
    \AlphAlph{\value{labelcellcount}}%
  }
\newcommand\labelcell[1]
  {%
    \refstepcounter{labelcellcount}%
    \label{#1}%
    \aftergroup\incelllabelcellcount
  }

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\RowSize}{3cm}
\begin{tabular}{|p{\RowSize}|p{\RowSize}|p{\RowSize}|}

\hline
\labelcell{cell:one} \blindduck & \labelcell{cell:two}Two &
\labelcell{cell:three}Three \\
\hline
Four\labelcell{cell:four} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\
\hline
Seven\labelcell{cell:seven} & Eight\labelcell{cell:eight} &
Nine\labelcell{cell:nine} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]